# customizable cross-validation in h2o (features that depend on the training set)

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o

I have a model where some of the input features are calculated from the training dataset (e.g. average or median of a value). I am trying to perform n-fold cross validation on this model, but that means that the values for these features would be different depending on the samples selected for training/validation for each fold. Is there a way in h2o (I'm using it in R) to perhaps pass a funtion that calculates those features once the training set has been determined?

It seems like a pretty intuitive feature to have, but I have not been able to find any documentation on something like it out-of-the-box. Does it exist? If so, could someone point me to a resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this while using the built-in cross-validation in H2O.  If H2O were written in pure R or Python, then it would be easy to extend it to allow a user to pass in a function to create custom features within the cross-validation loop, however the core of H2O is written in Java, so automatically translating an arbitrary user-defined function from R or Python, first into a REST call and then into Java is not trivial.

Instead, what you'd have to do is write a loop to do the cross-validation yourself and compute the features within the loop.

It sounds like you may be doing target encoding (or something similar), and if that's the case, you'll be interested in this [PR](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/2029) to add target encoding in H2O.  In the discussion, we talk about the same issue that you're having.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had a look at the PR and it does look similar to what I need but I was hoping you could customize it since I need to perform other operations besides the average.

This might be slightly off topic, but I have been trying to find a workaround where I don't have to perform the cross validation myself. I have already run H2O's cross-validation; is there a way to use the cross-validated models to perform predictions as you normally would with a regular model? I couldn't find this in the documentation.